# Cascading a WMTS from MapBox to GeoServer HTTP response 401

Tags: mapbox, geoserver

I'm trying to cascade a MapBox style through GeoServer as a cascaded WMTS, though I get the following error when trying to add a new WMTS data store:

```
WMTS Connection test failed: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: <wmts url here>
```

I'm using the WMTS URL from the "share" page with the default public access token.  This URL seems to work just fine in ArcMap, so I have a feeling it's not an authentication issue, but perhaps something to do with GeoServer translating MapBox.  Any insight is much appreciated.  Thank you.

Edit: the capabilities document is below:

```
<Capabilities xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wmts/1.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wmts/1.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wmts/1.0/wmtsGetCapabilities_response.xsd" version="1.0.0">
<ows:ServiceIdentification>
<ows:Title>Mapbox</ows:Title>
<ows:ServiceType>OGC WMTS</ows:ServiceType>
<ows:ServiceTypeVersion>1.0.0</ows:ServiceTypeVersion>
</ows:ServiceIdentification>
<ows:OperationsMetadata>
<ows:Operation name="GetCapabilities">
<ows:DCP>
<ows:HTTP>
<ows:Get xlink:href="https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/">
<ows:Constraint name="GetEncoding">
<ows:AllowedValues>
<ows:Value>RESTful</ows:Value>
</ows:AllowedValues>
</ows:Constraint>
</ows:Get>
</ows:HTTP>
</ows:DCP>
</ows:Operation>
<ows:Operation name="GetTile">
<ows:DCP>
<ows:HTTP>
<ows:Get xlink:href="https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/">
<ows:Constraint name="GetEncoding">
<ows:AllowedValues>
<ows:Value>RESTful</ows:Value>
</ows:AllowedValues>
</ows:Constraint>
</ows:Get>
</ows:HTTP>
</ows:DCP>
</ows:Operation>
</ows:OperationsMetadata>
<Contents>
<Layer>
<ows:Title></ows:Title>
<ows:Identifier></ows:Identifier>
<ows:Abstract>© OSM</ows:Abstract>
<ows:WGS84BoundingBox crs="urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:2:84">
<ows:LowerCorner>-180 -85.051129</ows:LowerCorner>
<ows:UpperCorner>179.976804 85.051129</ows:UpperCorner>
</ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
<Style isDefault="true">
<ows:Identifier>default</ows:Identifier>
</Style>
<Format>image/jpeg</Format>
<TileMatrixSetLink>
<TileMatrixSet>GoogleMapsCompatible</TileMatrixSet>
</TileMatrixSetLink>
<ResourceURL format="image/jpeg" resourceType="tile" template="https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/"/>
</Layer>
<TileMatrixSet>
<ows:Title>GoogleMapsCompatible</ows:Title>
<ows:Abstract>GoogleMapsCompatible EPSG:3857</ows:Abstract>
<ows:Identifier>GoogleMapsCompatible</ows:Identifier>
<ows:SupportedCRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857</ows:SupportedCRS>
<TileMatrix>
<ows:Identifier>0</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>279541132.0143589</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>512</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>512</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>1</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>1</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
<TileMatrix>
<ows:Identifier>1</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>139770566.00717944</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>512</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>512</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>2</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>2</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
<TileMatrix>
<ows:Identifier>2</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>69885283.00358972</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>512</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>512</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>4</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>4</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
<TileMatrix>
<ows:Identifier>3</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>34942641.50179486</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>512</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>512</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>8</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>8</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
<TileMatrix>
<ows:Identifier>4</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>17471320.75089743</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>512</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>512</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>16</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>16</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
<TileMatrix>
<ows:Identifier>5</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>8735660.375448715</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>512</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>512</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>32</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>32</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
<TileMatrix>
<ows:Identifier>6</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>4367830.1877243575</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>512</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>512</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>64</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>64</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
<TileMatrix>
<ows:Identifier>7</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>2183915.0938621787</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>512</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>512</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>128</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>128</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
<TileMatrix>
<ows:Identifier>8</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>1091957.5469310894</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>512</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>512</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>256</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>256</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
<TileMatrix>
<ows:Identifier>9</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>545978.7734655447</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>512</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>512</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>512</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>512</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
<TileMatrix>
<ows:Identifier>10</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>272989.38673277234</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>512</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>512</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>1024</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>1024</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
<TileMatrix>
<ows:Identifier>11</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>136494.69336638617</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>512</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>512</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>2048</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>2048</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
<TileMatrix>
<ows:Identifier>12</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>68247.34668319309</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>512</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>512</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>4096</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>4096</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
<TileMatrix>
<ows:Identifier>13</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>34123.67334159654</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>512</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>512</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>8192</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>8192</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
<TileMatrix>
<ows:Identifier>14</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>17061.83667079827</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>512</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>512</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>16384</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>16384</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
<TileMatrix>
<ows:Identifier>15</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>8530.918335399136</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>512</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>512</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>32768</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>32768</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
<TileMatrix>
<ows:Identifier>16</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>4265.459167699568</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>512</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>512</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>65536</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>65536</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
<TileMatrix>
<ows:Identifier>17</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>2132.729583849784</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>512</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>512</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>131072</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>131072</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
<TileMatrix>
<ows:Identifier>18</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>1066.364791924892</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>512</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>512</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>262144</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>262144</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
<TileMatrix>
<ows:Identifier>19</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>533.182395962446</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>512</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>512</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>524288</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>524288</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
<TileMatrix>
<ows:Identifier>20</ows:Identifier>
<ScaleDenominator>266.591197981223</ScaleDenominator>
<TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
<TileWidth>512</TileWidth>
<TileHeight>512</TileHeight>
<MatrixWidth>1048576</MatrixWidth>
<MatrixHeight>1048576</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
</TileMatrixSet>
</Contents>
<ServiceMetadataURL xlink:href="https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/"/>
</Capabilities>
```

Comment: can you check the log files at both ends to see if there is any more info. This is definitely an authentication issue, possibly try turning `Use HTTP connection pooling` off

Comment: This may be a dumb question (I apologize), but how do I access the log files for mapbox? The log for GeoServer doesn't seem very helpful: "198 ERROR [data.ows] - Failed to execute request https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/..."  I'm pretty new to both MapBox and Geoserver, so I could be missing something.

Comment: Also, still receiving the same 401 code with `Use HTTP connection pooling` turned off.

Comment: I don't know much about mapbox, is it a real WMTS service with getcapabilities requests etc or just looks a bit like one with x,y,z tiles?

Comment: No, MapBox itself is not a WMTS or WMS service (I think I read that they never plan on providing one), but they do provide a service that translates a map in MapBox into a format that WMTS readers, like ArcMap and QGIS (as per their suggestions and tutorial) can read.  They simply provide a URL endpoint for this which is provided to ArcMap/QGIS.  Viewing this endpoint in Chrome, I see that it is, in fact, a XML capabilities document, which appears to refference a GetCapabilities API.
`http://schemas.opengis.net/wmts/1.0/wmtsGetCapabilities_response.xsd"`

Comment: Can you please add a copy of the getcapabilities file

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what is the best way to do that?  I'd rather not link it here since it contains the secure access token.

Comment: Edit out the token

Comment: I was just trying to avoid pasting a large xml document into this thread, but you'll find it appended to the original question.  Thanks.